# Extracting extension from a file in C#?

Tags: c#, file, extract, information-extraction

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Program
{

    class Program
    {

        public static string *GetExtension*(string cale) //GetExtension is an error
        {
            string fisier, extensie;
            cale = @"D:\dir1\dir2\";
            fisier = @"D:\dir1\dir2\fisier.txt";        

            extensie = Path.GetExtension(fisier);

            System.Console.WriteLine("Extensie: {0} returneaza {1}", fisier, extensie);

            extensie = Path.GetExtension(cale);

            System.Console.WriteLine("Extensie: {0} returneaza {1}", fisier, extensie);
        }
    }
}
```

I apologize for this amateur post.

I don't understand the error `"Program.Program.GetExtension(string)': not all code paths return a value"`

Can anyone tell me what have I done wrong, please?

(oh and fisier means file, cale mean path and extensie mean extension in my language).
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: before I post something, I think you got enough answers

Comment: Also, you're passing in cale but then reassigning it before using it. I hope you were just testing something because this seems strange.

Comment: I had to replace "public static string" with "public static void" ... and now it's working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function is supposed to return a string but you have no return statement

add

```
return extensie;
```

before the first `}`

alternatively if you aren't wanting a return value and are just wanting the console.writelines simply change `public static string` to be `public static void` and then you won't need a return value

Answer (score 1):

Your function is expected to return a string. You are not returning anything in the entire function.

Somewhere in the function you should have a statement like:

```
return extensie;
```

Answer (score 1):

By defining your method like

```
public static string GetExtension(string cale) //GetExtension is an error
```

You say that your method will return a string.

Your method, doesn't return anything by just outputs something to the screen. So alter it like this:

```
public static void GetExtension(string cale) //GetExtension is an error
```

or, if you do want to return something, make sure you put this line:

```
return extensie;
```

at the end of your method (before the closing brace)

I would suggest looking into the 'Return Values' section on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) :)

Answer (score 0):

you must add return to your function

```
public static string *GetExtension*(string cale) //GetExtension is an error
{

    string fisier, extensie;

    cale = @"D:\dir1\dir2\";

    fisier = @"D:\dir1\dir2\fisier.txt";


    extensie = Path.GetExtension(fisier);

    System.Console.WriteLine("Extensie: {0} returneaza {1}", fisier, extensie);


    extensie = Path.GetExtension(cale);

    System.Console.WriteLine("Extensie: {0} returneaza {1}", fisier, extensie);

    return extensie; //<----------------
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to return a string from your function, e.g.

```
return extensie;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your language is french, so if you like, I can give you a translation but to answer your question in english:

The best way is to replace public static String with public static void

Also, I don't see why you have stars around GetExtension

giving:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Program {
    class Program
    {
        public static void GetExtension(string cale) //GetExtension is an error
        {
        string fisier, extensie;
        cale = @"D:\dir1\dir2\";
        fisier = @"D:\dir1\dir2\fisier.txt";

        extensie = Path.GetExtension(fisier);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Extensie: {0} returneaza {1}", fisier, extensie);
        extensie = Path.GetExtension(cale);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Extensie: {0} returneaza {1}", fisier, extensie);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The stars ment to be "Italic" font.

Answer (score -1):

Your method is marked as "public static string", which means that you need a "return string;" statement. If you do not want the method to return a value then you can replace the method definition with "public static void" which means "I'm not going to return anything"

On a side note:
You can use the [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class to get the extension of the file in question. Its less code and has been done for you :)

For example:

```
        FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(path);
        string extension = fInfo.Extension;
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but I'm guessing because the original poster wanted to know about the error, not a method to get a file extension.

Comment: Wasn't me that down voted, but guessing because you didn't answer the actual question - I don't understand the error "Program.Program.GetExtension(string)': not all code paths return a value". Can anyone tell me what have I done wrong, please?

Comment: I'll edit, to correct, however I think this answer is more elegant than the posted code. Re-InventingTheWheel--

Comment: @ry8806 I prefer Path.GetExtension.